# Update State-variable Whenever CoreData is Updated in SwiftUI

Tags: core-data, swiftui

After updating some data from CoreData, I also want to update a `State`-variable to the number of returned results.

When CoreData is changed, the `Stepper` should always be set to the number of returned results. However, `onAppear` fires also when I use the `Stepper`. How can I check in `onAppear` whether CoreData was changed or the `Stepper` was used? Is that even possible?

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
@State var numberOfResults = 0

@FetchRequest(entity: YourModel.entity(), sortDescriptors: [], predicate:NSPredicate(format: "isSelected == %@", NSNumber(booleanLiteral: true))) var objects: FetchedResults<YourModel>

var body: some View{
    return VStack{

        Stepper("text", value: $numberOfResults, in: 0...objects.wrappedValue.count, step:5)
            .onReceive(objects.publisher, perform: {_ in
                self.numberOfResults = self.objects.count
                print("onReceive")
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use @FetchRequest and onReceive numberOfResults will be updated when the publisher sends a message

```
import SwiftUI

struct DidSetCoreData: View {
    @State var numberOfResults = 0
    @State var initSetup1: Bool = true
    @State var initSetup2: Bool = true
    @State var adjustedCount = 0
    @FetchRequest(entity: YourModel.entity(), sortDescriptors: [], predicate:NSPredicate(format: "isSelected == %@", NSNumber(booleanLiteral: true))) var objects: FetchedResults<YourModel>

    var body: some View{
    return VStack{
            Text("Total Count= \(objects.count)")
            Text("Adjusted Total = \($adjustedCount.wrappedValue)")
            //You need the separate adjusted count variable to save the changes

            //Option 1 Stepper - Keeps the max step flexible, eliminates the need for the numberOfResults var
            Stepper("AdjTotal - FlexibleMax", value: $adjustedCount, in: 0...objects.count, step:5)
            .onReceive(objects.publisher.count(), perform: {count in
                //onReceive will be called everytime there is a change to objects.count or body refresh
                print("onReceive - Option 1")
                if self.initSetup1{
                    //The variable will only be setup once
                    self.adjustedCount = count
                    self.initSetup1 = false
                    print("initSetupComplete - Option 1")
                }
            })

            //Option 2 Stepper
            Stepper("AdjTotal - initMax", value: $adjustedCount, in: 0...$numberOfResults.wrappedValue, step:5)

            .onReceive(objects.publisher.count(), perform: {count in
                //onReceive will be called everytime there is a change to objects.count or body refresh
                print("onReceive - Option 2")
                if self.initSetup2{
                    //The variables will only be setup once
                    self.numberOfResults = count //Limits the max step to only the original count
                    self.adjustedCount = self.numberOfResults
                    self.initSetup2 = false
                    print("initSetupComplete - Option 2")
                }
            })
            //Option 3 Stepper - Limits the StepperMax to the Stepper value
            Stepper("AdjTotal - ValueMax", value: $numberOfResults, in: 0...$numberOfResults.wrappedValue, step:5)
            .onReceive(objects.publisher.count(), perform: {count in
                //onReceive will be called everytime there is a change to objects.count or body refresh
                print("onReceive - Option 3")
                if self.initSetup3{
                    //The variable will only be setup once
                    self.numberOfResults = count
                    self.initSetup3 = false
                    print("initSetupComplete - Option 3")
                }
           })
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `onAppear` will also fire every time when change the state variable. I use the state variable in a Stepper. So whenever I use the `Stepper` it is set to the `numberOfResults`. I changed the code to make it clearer. Do you also know how I can make the Stepper working?

Comment: There are two ways you can try. But it depends if you need the FetchRequest variable on this view for something else. If you don't need the  FetchRequest for anything else a one-time FetchRequest during init() can be used to setup the numberOfResults variable. https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/FetchingObjects.html

If you do need the FetchRequest I changed the code above to include an initSetup Bool.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `@State var numberOfResults`. You can use just `objects.count` in a `Text()`. The wrapper `@FetchRequest` do all the work for you. Whenever you add a `YourModel` entity object into `ManagedObjectContext`, it will trigger `FetchRequest` to refresh and give you actual result. `@FetchRequest` is already do things like `@State`

Comment: I need it as a state variable since i use the variable in a `Stepper`. And it should initially be set to the maximum.