# Why does using FetchedResults work for Text and not TextField? SwiftUI, CoreData/ FetchRequest

Tags: core-data, swiftui, nsfetchrequest

I am getting CoreData properties from a FetchRequest and want to use it to pre-populate a text field (a user's Email).

Here is the `FetchRequest`

```
     @FetchRequest(
       entity: Account.entity(),
       sortDescriptors:[
       NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Account.id, ascending: true)
       ]
     )var accounts: FetchedResults<Account>
```

- Note I have all of the proper `persistant container` and `@environment` stuff set up to use `@FetchRequest` like this.

Then in my View stack I have:

```
var body: some View{
  ZStack {
    Form {
      Section(header: Text("EMAIL")) {
        ForEach(accounts, id: \.self) {account in
          TextField("Email", text:account.email)    // This is where I get an error (see error below)                         
          }
        }
    }
```

- Error is : *Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'Binding<String>'*

However is I simply list `accounts` in a textfield it works. Like so:

```
var body: some View{
  ZStack {
    Form {
      List(accounts, id: \.self) { account in
         Text(account.email ?? "Unknown")
      }
    }
  }
```

**Why does the second code that uses `List` not give me the same error?**

I thought it had something to do with the `??` operator but after research I realized that it perfectly fine to do given that `email` in my coredata object is `String?`.

Now my thought is that I am getting this error here because TextField needs a `Binding` wrapper? If that is true I'm not sure how to get this to work. All I want to do is have this `TextField` pre-populated with the single email record the `FetchRequest` retrieves from my `Account` Core Data object.

Thanks.

Edit: I want to add that I have found this post https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-fix-cannot-convert-value-of-type-string-to-expected-argument-type-binding-string

and now I think what I need to do is store this `account.email` result into a `State` variable. My question still remains however, I'm not sure how to do this as I am looking for clean way to do it right in the view stack here. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer details getting a CoreData request into a @State variable:
[Update State-variable Whenever CoreData is Updated in SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59954342/update-state-variable-whenever-coredata-is-updated-in-swiftui)

What you'll end up with is something like this:

```
@State var text = ""
```

In your view (maybe attached to your ZStack) an `onReceive` property that tells you when you have new CoreData to look at:

```
ZStack {
...
}.onReceive(accounts.publisher, perform: { _ in
                //you can reference self.accounts at this point
                //grab the index you want and set self.text equal to it
            })
```

However, you'll have to do some clever stuff to make sure setting it the first time and then probably not modifying it again once the user starts typing.

This could also get complicated by the fact that you're in a list and have multiple accounts -- at this point, I may split every list item out into its own view with a separate @State variable.

Keep in mind, you can also write custom bindings like this:

```
Binding<String>(get: {
//return a value from your CoreData model
}, set: { newValue in })
```

**But** unless you get more clever with how you're returning in the `get` section, the user won't be able to edit the test.  You could shadow it with another @State variable behind the scenes, too.

Finally, here's a thread on the Apple Developer forums that gets even more in-depth about possible ways to address this: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/128195

Answer (score 1):

`TextField` needs a *binding* to a string variable. `Account` is and ObservableObject, like all NSManagedObjects, so if you refactor your `TextField` into a separate View you could do this:

```swift
Form {
    Section(header: Text("EMAIL")) {
        ForEach(accounts, id: \.self) { account in
            Row(account: account)
        }
    }
}

...

struct Row: View {
    @ObservedObject var account: Account
    
    var body: some View {
        TextField("Email", text: $account.email)
    }
}
```

Note the `$account.email` — the `$` turns this into a binding.

Unfortunately, this new code also fails, because `email` is a `String?` (i.e., it can be nil) but `TextField` doesn’t allow nil. Thankfully that’s not too hard to fix, because we can define a custom Binding like so:

```swift
struct Row: View {
    @ObservedObject var account: Account
    
    var email: Binding<String> {
        Binding<String>(get: {
            if let email = account.email {
                return email
            } else {
                return "Unknown"
            }
        },
        set: { account.email = $0 })
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        TextField("Email", text: email)
    }
}
```

Notice we don’t have a `$` this time, because `email` is itself a Binding.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. When I use this code, I get an error on the line with `if let` that says *initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not String*

Comment: Oh, usually a Swift NsManagedObject’s properties are optional. If Account.email isn’t optional, then `TextField("Email", text: $account.email)` from the first part of my answer should work.